# Is it correct to use nested object pointer of 'source' of event?

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling

Let me introduce this question by an example:

We have UserNotification class. It has the information about notification, possible user options.

```
public class UserNotification
{
    // Event fired on notification broadcast
    public event EventHandler<NotifyEventArgs> Notification;

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<NotificationResults> Options { get; set; }
    // ...

    // This function is called to raise notification 
    public void Notify()
    {
        if (Notification != null) Notification(null, new NotifyEventArgs());
    }
}
```

So we have a bunch of notifications. Each time when some part of the program needs to raise a notification (for the user) it takes some notification object and calls Notify() method. Then Notification event is fired and all listeners may process this notification (display it somewhere in gui, show dialog box etc.)

Finally there are the number of such notifications from different parts of the software and even plugins. And notification listeners, most probably, would love to listem them all. So the next thing that comes in mind is NotificationManager. It has collection of UserNotification and NotificationRaised event which is fired when any of registered notifications fires its Notification event

```
public class NotificationManager
{
    public event EventHandler NotificationRaised;

    private List<UserNotification> _notifications;

    public void AddNotification(UserNotification notification)
    {
        _notifications.Add(notification);
        notification.Notification += () => 
                  { 
                      if (NotificationRaised != null) NotificationRaised(???, ???) 
                  };
    }
```

And here comes the question. Look at **NotificationRaised(???, someEventArgs)**. At this point we need to pass pointer to the source notification so that listener could work with this particular notification. The NotificationManager's event handler has 'source' field that looks exactly as what we need... The question is:

Is it correct to put the Notification pointer as source? Or by design and some good reasons the source **MUST** be the object which is firing the event?

In other words, if one looks at the example, would it be 'as intended behavior'?

Answer (score 1):

If you are forwarding an event, I see no problem with forwarding the source from the original event.

Comment: Me too! But I thought that there could be some cases why it is bad. Or restrictions. Some 'hidden features' of .Net standard library that could play in this case. Or some practice saying that doing this may result as 'it doesn't work as intended'.

Comment: @MajesticRa: If it helps, I've done this before without any issues.

Comment: Thank you! Since nobody is proofing the bad side of the subject, it is really good for me to hear opinions of experienced developers.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it is okay to replace the sender with something new. The most obvious example where i already did this was a proxy object for something else. There i subscribed to every event of the real class and forwarded the event with a replaced sender (the proxy itself).

But maybe this change to the implementation will give you enough freedom for the future:

```
public void AddNotification(UserNotification notification)
{
    AddNotification(notification, false);
}

public void AddNotification(UserNotification notification, bool useOriginalSender)
{
    _notifications.Add(notification);
    notification.Notification += (originalSender, e) =>
                {
                    var temp = NotificationRaised;

                    if (temp != null)
                    {
                        var sender = useOriginalSender ? originalSender : this;
                        temp(sender, NotifyEventArgs.Empty);
                    }
                };
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Thinking of proxies... I believe, such forwarding is really "what is intended" for the proxy case. That persuades me more that all these cases is why such 'sender' arguments exists at all.